# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

Tags: c#, .net, maui

хочу заполнить listView объектами, но что-то пошло не так... Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема:

СontentPage, где находится ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SmartYard.Session.NewsPage"
             Title="Новости">
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <ListView
                ItemsSource="{Binding NewsViewModel.News}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <VerticalStackLayout
                                Padding="10">
                                <Label
                                    Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                                <Label
                                    Text="{Binding Body}"/>
                                <Image
                                    Source="{Binding ImageHeader }"/>
                            </VerticalStackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

NewsPage.xaml.cs:

```
namespace SmartYard.Session;

public partial class NewsPage : ContentPage
{

    public NewsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new ViewModels.NewsViewModel();
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SmartYard.ViewModels
{
    public class NewsViewModel
    {
        
        public IList<Models.News> News { get; private set; }

        public NewsViewModel()
        {
            List<string> Images = new List<string>(){
                "https://avatarko.ru/img/kartinka/33/multfilm_lyagushka_32117.jpg",
                "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS_jiT_jx9pmDh4zQdyokPBv7dZzUNfnZjvDub-404q&s",
                "https://avatarko.ru/img/kartinka/1/Crazy_Frog.jpg"
            };
            News.Add(new Models.News()
            {
                Id = 0,
                Header = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
                Body = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan. Diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in. Rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec. Velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare. Iaculis urna id volutpat lacus. Adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim. Eros donec ac odio tempor. Egestas purus viverra accumsan in nisl. Lectus quam id leo in vitae turpis massa sed. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna et pharetra. Cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat.\r\n\r\nArcu dui vivamus arcu felis. Magna etiam tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. In vitae turpis massa sed elementum tempus egestas sed sed. Volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in. Eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida. Risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum. Quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit. Gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim. Amet dictum sit amet justo donec enim diam vulputate ut. Et malesuada fames ac turpis.",
                ImageResourses = Images,
                ImageResoursesCount = Images.Count,
                ImageHeader = Images[0]
            });

        }

    }
}
```

При попытке открытия страницы приложение останавливается и студия выдает ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нужно было что-то прописать в .csproj, манифестах, то я этого ничего не делал, подскажите, пожалуйста, если нужно :) Спасибо огромное!

Cтек вызовов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема за пределами показанного кода. Стек вызовов смотрите.

Comment: @aepot, гляньте пожалуйста (добавил в тему), я недавно в этой теме, не разбираюсь пока что вообще

Comment: Какой-то контрол не может создать.

Comment: А почему вы взяли, что проблема в `ListView`? Удалите весь XAML и запустите, будет ошибка? Если да, то проблема явно не тут. Вообще, вам в сообщение об ошибке пишет "Исключение было выброшено объектом вызова", то есть у вас есть гдето другой объект, который вызвал уже свое исключение, и обычно такие исключения пишутся в `InnerException` исключения, но у вас их непойми почему нету. Поизучайте ошибку, посмотрите вон "Копировать подробности", или попробуйте отловить ее кодом, может там будет `InnerException`.

Comment: А так, ошибка может что угодно значить, например [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70106839#comment124076739_70106839) у человека приложение падало из-за опечатки в XAML (`small`, а должно быть `Small`). Точней сказать тут вряд ли возможно (там правда Xamarin, но не думаю, что есть разница в этом случае).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, подскажите, пожалуйста, в логах отладки заметил такую строку перед этой ошибкой: `[TabLayout] MODE_SCROLLABLE + GRAVITY_FILL is not supported, GRAVITY_START will be used instead` может ли причина быть связанной с этим? Если да, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить? спасибо

Comment: Без понятия) Я не разработчик андройд приложений, не знаю их кухни) В интернете есть [такое](https://www.codepudding.com/other/331774.html), там встречается ваша ошибка у людей, но не уверен, что это связано с тем, что описано там как основной пост, который являлся [багом](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4506) MAIU, исправленном в 6.0.300-rc.2. Вы удалите элементы пока не пропадет ошибка, так отловите проблемное место, будет проще понять дальше что не так.